# UPS Rating API C# .Net

Tags: c#, ups

I am trying to get the UPS Rating API that now supports Time In Transit to work.  I have the latest WSDL (UPS API).  I keep getting an exception error "An exception has been raised as a result of client data." and I can not figure out what is the problem.  Note:  The "Rate" requestOption works with no issues - when TimeinTransit and DeliveryInformation data is commented out.

What could be wrong?  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is my C# code:

```
UPSRateWS.RequestType request = new UPSRateWS.RequestType();
String[] requestOption = { "ratetimeintransit" };
request.RequestOption = requestOption;
request.SubVersion = "1601";

rateRequest.Request = request;

UPSRateWS.ShipmentType shipment = new UPSRateWS.ShipmentType();
UPSRateWS.ShipperType shipper = new UPSRateWS.ShipperType();

UPSRateWS.ShipmentRatingOptionsType shipmentRatingOptions = new 
     UPSRateWS.ShipmentRatingOptionsType();
shipmentRatingOptions.NegotiatedRatesIndicator = "";
shipmentRatingOptions.RateChartIndicator = "";

shipment.ShipmentRatingOptions = shipmentRatingOptions;

UPSRateWS.TimeInTransitRequestType timeInTransit = new 
     UPSRateWS.TimeInTransitRequestType();
UPSRateWS.PickupType pickupInTransitType = new UPSRateWS.PickupType();

pickupInTransitType.Date = "20170414";
pickupInTransitType.Time = "1630";

timeInTransit.Pickup = pickupInTransitType;
timeInTransit.PackageBillType = "02";

shipment.NumOfPieces = "1";

shipment.DeliveryTimeInformation = timeInTransit;

UPSRateWS.ShipmentWeightType shipWeightType = new 
     UPSRateWS.ShipmentWeightType();
shipWeightType.Weight = "10.80";

UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType shipWeightUOM = new 
     UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType();
shipWeightUOM.Code = "LBS";
shipWeightUOM.Description = "pounds";
shipWeightType.UnitOfMeasurement = shipWeightUOM;
shipment.ShipmentTotalWeight = shipWeightType;

shipper.ShipperNumber = "XXXXXX";

UPSRateWS.AddressType shipperAddress = new UPSRateWS.AddressType();
string testAddr = "7650 Tyler Blvd";
String[] addressLine = { testAddr };
shipperAddress.AddressLine = addressLine;
shipperAddress.City = "Mentor";
shipperAddress.PostalCode = "44060";
shipperAddress.StateProvinceCode = "OH";
shipperAddress.CountryCode = "US";
shipperAddress.AddressLine = addressLine;
shipper.Address = shipperAddress;

shipment.Shipper = shipper;

UPSRateWS.ShipFromType shipFrom = new UPSRateWS.ShipFromType();
UPSRateWS.ShipAddressType shipFromAddress = new UPSRateWS.ShipAddressType();

string testAddr2 = "";
String[] addressLine1 = { testAddr2 };
shipFromAddress.AddressLine = addressLine1;
shipFromAddress.City = "";
shipFromAddress.PostalCode = "45069";
shipFromAddress.StateProvinceCode = "OH";
shipFromAddress.CountryCode = "US";
shipFrom.Address = shipFromAddress;

shipment.ShipFrom = shipFrom;

UPSRateWS.ShipToType shipTo = new UPSRateWS.ShipToType();
UPSRateWS.ShipToAddressType shipToAddress = new UPSRateWS.ShipToAddressType();

string testAddr3 = "7650 Tyler Blvd";
String[] addressLine2 = { testAddr3 };
shipToAddress.AddressLine = addressLine2;
shipToAddress.City = "Mentor";
shipToAddress.PostalCode = "44060";
shipToAddress.StateProvinceCode = "OH";
shipToAddress.CountryCode = "US";
shipToAddress.ResidentialAddressIndicator = "1";
shipTo.Address = shipToAddress;

shipment.ShipTo = shipTo;

UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType service = new UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType();
service.Code = "03";    
shipment.Service = service;

UPSRateWS.PackageType package = new UPSRateWS.PackageType();
UPSRateWS.PackageWeightType packageWeight = new UPSRateWS.PackageWeightType();
packageWeight.Weight = "10.80";

UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType uom = new UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType();
uom.Code = "LBS";
uom.Description = "pounds";
packageWeight.UnitOfMeasurement = uom;
package.PackageWeight = packageWeight;

UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType packType = new UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType();
packType.Code = "02";
package.PackagingType = packType;

UPSRateWS.PackageServiceOptionsType packServType = new 
     UPSRateWS.PackageServiceOptionsType();
UPSRateWS.InsuredValueType insuredValueType = new UPSRateWS.InsuredValueType();
insuredValueType.CurrencyCode = "USD";
insuredValueType.MonetaryValue = "65.75";
packServType.DeclaredValue = insuredValueType;

UPSRateWS.ShipperDeclaredValueType shipperDeclaredValueType = new 
     UPSRateWS.ShipperDeclaredValueType();
shipperDeclaredValueType.CurrencyCode = "USD";
shipperDeclaredValueType.MonetaryValue = "65.75";
packServType.ShipperDeclaredValue = shipperDeclaredValueType;
package.PackageServiceOptions = packServType;

UPSRateWS.PackageType[] pkgArray = { package };
shipment.Package = pkgArray;
rateRequest.Shipment = shipment;

UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType pickupType = new UPSRateWS.CodeDescriptionType();
pickupType.Code = "01";
pickupType.Description = "Daily Pickup";
rateRequest.PickupType = pickupType;

UPSRateWS.RateResponse rateResponse = myRatePortTypeClient.ProcessRate(upss, 
     rateRequest);
```

Comment: Create procedures. This code is hard to understand in such form. In which line error appears?

Comment: This will be in Functions, but for ease to add to this forum I just lumped it all together.  The last line of code "UPSRateWS.RateResponse rateResponse = myRatePortTypeClient.ProcessRate(upss, 
     rateRequest);" is the call to process the rate and that is where the error comes back from UPS.  All the code above that line is setting all the values for the request to send.  Note:  the upss object in the last line function is the credentials that get passed - which for security reasons I did not include.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include both the "rate" option and the "ratetimeintransit" options:

```
String[] requestOption = { "rate","ratetimeintransit" };
```